# why docker run is not starting?

Tags: node.js, docker

I installed nodejs and build a simple docker file and build it. When I want to start the server it is not listened in the docker ps and after 30sec it closes. why ? I watched a video and there is working.

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine

ADD . .

CMD ["node" "app.js"];
```

nodejs

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');
const { processenv } = require('processenv');

const message = processenv('MESSAGE', 'Hello World');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'content-type': 'text/html'
  });
  res.write(message);
  res.end();
});

server.listen(3000);
```

command

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -e MESSAGE='Hallo 44' a32efcf059a9
```

docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                            PORTS     NAMES
ac4374aea2aa   a32efcf059a9   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 seconds ago       Exited (127) 9 seconds ago                  elastic_lichterman
65860beb10b5   a32efcf059a9   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Exited (127) About a minute ago             gracious_fermi
```

docker ps while its started:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS                            PORTS     NAMES
```

€:
if I start my container from docker desktop I got this:

```
invalid reference format
```

Comment: your container is exiting. You need to look at the container logs. or run the container without the `-d` flag so the container logs will stream you your STDOUT

Comment: if I make it with nginx it works, i think that is not the problem and if I want to start the image on my docker desktop I get invalid reference format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues with your Dockerfile. The CMD syntax you used is incorrect. Also, for NodeJS, you should have the WORKDIR defined. You also need to have `processenv` package installed.

It should work if you replace your Dockerfile with this:

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/app

RUN npm install processenv

ADD app.js /opt/app

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

You can run it with the command:

```
docker build -t nodejsapp . &&  docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -e MESSAGE='Hallo 44' nodejsapp
```